# In Chrome, Canvas Arcs are distorted when scaled up

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

The canvas context.arc() method draws distorted arcs when the context is scaled up.  It looks like the arcs are (poorly) approximated with a Bézier curve.  Works correctly in Firefox.  Untested in IE.

I observed this problem some time ago, but recently it seems to have become much worse (I'm not sure when).

I found a number of canvas issues on StackOverflow, but not this one.  If you know it to be a manifestation of an already-reported issue, please forward a link.  I've already reported it via Chrome's Help/Report Issue mechanism.

Before I write my own, does anyone have a workaround? ...perhaps an overloaded or alternative 'arc' method?

The following demo is viewable here: http://keveney.com/chrome_arc_bug.html

```js
paint_canvas();

// simulate circle with line segments
//
function regular_polygon(ctx, segments, cx, cy, r) {
  var i, a;

  ctx.moveTo(cx + r, cy);

  for (i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    a = (Math.PI * 2) * i / segments;
    ctx.lineTo(cx + r * Math.cos(a), cy + r * Math.sin(a));
  }

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function paint_canvas() {
  var ctx;

  // draw unscaled circle using canvas 'arc' method
  //
  ctx = document.getElementById('canv').getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1.25;
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw enclosing polygons
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#c00";
  regular_polygon(ctx, 36, 250, 250, 215);
  regular_polygon(ctx, 36, 250, 250, 185);

  // the same but scaled up from smaller units
  //
  ctx = document.getElementById('canv2').getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.scale(100, 100);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1.25 / 100;
  ctx.arc(2.5, 2.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#c00";
  regular_polygon(ctx, 36, 2.5, 2.5, 2.15);
  regular_polygon(ctx, 36, 2.5, 2.5, 1.85);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
canvas {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<p>Chrome arc scaling bug</p>
<canvas id="canv" height=500 width=500></canvas>
<canvas id="canv2" height=500 width=500></canvas>

<p>expected: Both images should be identical.</p>
<p>actual: Arc in second image is badly distorted.</p>
<p>Issue reported 6/17/2015.</p>
<p>tested with 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit)</p>
<p>This issue was observed some time ago, but has gotten worse in recent releases of Chrome. Not tested on Internet Explorer. If you find a convenient solution,
  please notify Matt Keveney, matt@keveney.com</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This effect stems from an approximation of a circle with a small radius, it looks more like a square than a circle.

[image]

If you knowingly will make this kind of circles, I'd recommend making a function that draws a circle with a radius which will generate a good approximation of a circle that will scale well (I chose a radius of 10 in my example below), then adjust the parameters to achieve the wanted circle.

```
function drawSmallArc(x,y,r,scale) {
    var adjust = 10/r;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00f";
    ctx.scale(scale/adjust, scale/adjust);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.25 / scale * adjust;
    ctx.arc(x*adjust, y*adjust,r*adjust,0,2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

**In action below**

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//Two referense circles.
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0"; //green
ctx.lineWidth = 1.25;
ctx.arc(250, 250, 180, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0"; //green
ctx.lineWidth = 1.25;
ctx.arc(250, 250, 220, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();

//Red circle using OP's original circle
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#f00"; //Red
ctx.lineWidth = 1.25 / 100;
ctx.scale(100,100);
ctx.arc(2.5, 2.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

//blue circle with better approximation of circle.
drawSmallArc(2.5,2.5,2,100);

function drawSmallArc(x,y,r,scale) {
    var adjust = 10/r;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00f";
    ctx.scale(scale/adjust, scale/adjust);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.25 / scale * adjust;
    ctx.arc(x*adjust, y*adjust,r*adjust,0,2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=500 width=500></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't think your original explanation is accurate; you've illustrated a low-resolution bitmap rendition that has been scaled up...that's not what's happening here.  (note that this is a bug in Chrome only, not a general issue).Your workaround merely reverses the scaling effect, which I suppose does the job, but isn't really the approach I was hoping for.  But, thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the problem for now, using a high-count polygon. Mine is not a fully-compatible drop-in replacement for arc, so it will not be repeated here. It is much like the function used in the above sample code to render the red reference polygons.

I remain interested in a better solution, or a Chrome update that fixes the problem, in case anyone finds it.